# Tkinter custom background image

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to put as the entire app background a custom image.
I read somewhere that I have to do something like this:

```
root = Tk()
bg_image = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Matteo/Desktop/fisica.png")
app = App(root,image=bg_image)
root.title("Fisica")
root.geometry("330x470")
root.mainloop()
```

When I try to run the code, it says:
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'image'

I can't understand what's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add the image to a label:

```
 Label(root, image=bg_image)
```

then use `.pack()` or `.grid()` to position the label to the grid.

see here:

[how to put a image as a background in tkinter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158552/how-to-put-a-image-as-a-background-in-tkinter-in-python)

You could have found this by searching stackoverflow/google.

You can't add the image directly to the root window.

Comment: So can't do something similar to root["bg"] = "red" ?

Comment: No, the root contains `Tk()` class, it can't handle a background option.