# How to place widgets in tkinter above the background image using classes

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to place widgets above the background image but the background image is appearing above the widgets.

**Code**

```
import tkinter as tk    

class baseclass(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.title("REMOTE STREETLIGHT MANAGEMENT")

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (startpage,firstPage):

            page_name = F.__name__

            frame = F(parent=container,controller=self)

            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("startpage")

    def show_frame(self,page_name):

        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class startpage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.controller = controller
        c=tk.Canvas(self,bg="red", height=250,width=300)
        img1_path=r"D:\StreetLight\sl1.gif"
        img1=tk.PhotoImage(file=img1_path)
        background_label = tk.Label(self, image=img1)


        title_label=tk.Label(self,text='Welcome to the Remote Monitoring portal\n')
        title_label.pack()
        background_label.image=img1
        background_label.pack()

        #attempt to login button
        attempt_login = tk.Button(self,text="Login",
                                  command=lambda: controller.show_frame("firstPage"))
        attempt_login.pack(pady=4)
        c.pack()


class firstPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.controller=controller

        title_label=tk.Label(self,text='Welcome to the Remote Monitoring portal\n')
        title_label.pack()

        select_area_label=tk.Label(self,text="SELECT AREA\n")
        select_area_label.pack()

        back = tk.Button(self,text="Sign Out",
                                  command=lambda: controller.show_frame("startpage"))
        back.pack(pady=4)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = baseclass()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158552/how-to-put-a-image-as-a-background-in-tkinter-in-python) answers, to use an image as background in tkinter, you should define its position with `place` instead of `pack`. In your code, try replacing:

```
background_label.pack()
```

with

```
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

Comment: Do you even know what does `relwidth=1, relheight=1` do and mean? And what's the difference without them? If not, it's better to flag the answer as duplicate than to answer it with another answer.