# How to have an background image and buttons on it in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a simple Python 3 program using `tkinter`. it should display a background picture and a button.

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

window = tkinter.Tk()
file = Image.open('/Users/dariushmazlumi/Desktop/p.jpg')
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file)
background = tkinter.Label(window, image=img)
background.image = img
background.pack()
window.minsize(height=window.winfo_height(), width=window.winfo_width())
number = 0
def buttonclicked():
    global number
    number = number+1
    button.configure(text=number)
button = tkinter.Button(window, text=0, command=buttonclicked)
button.grid(column=1, row=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Prior to this, I tried using `button.pack()`, but it shows button under the image, not on it(maybe the image is not background).

Next, I tried using `button.grid()`. It runs on the terminal with no error, but no visible output! It just runs. I don't know why.

I want my program to display an image and buttons on it (like a desktop for example).

Comment: You can't put tkinter widgets on top of one another with the exception of a `Canvas`, which can contain them (as well as pure graphics), but still not on top of each other. In other words, you can't put a `Button` on top of a `Label`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to put a image as a background in tkinter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158552/how-to-put-a-image-as-a-background-in-tkinter-in-python)

Comment: If you run this code, you may notice an error message like `_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack`. I think that explains why the code doesn't work clearly enough.

Comment: @martineau: you _can_ put tkinter widgets on top of one another, including putting a button on top of a label. It may not be pretty, but there''s nothing to prevent you from doing it.

Comment: @Rawing run the second code. same error?

Comment: When I run the code I get the (expected) error "cannot use geometry manager grid inside .". It's expected because, like the complete error says, you're already using `pack`.

Comment: Same mistake, same error.

Comment: @martineau I didn't get it. can you write that code?

Comment: @Rawing weird! let me re-run my code again.

Comment: The question you are asking is unclear. Are you asking how to put a button on top of a label? Or, are you asking the more general question of how do you use an image as a background for an entire GUI window?

Comment: @Rawing I think you don't have an image in location '/Users/dariushmazlumi/Desktop/p.jpg' !

Comment: @BryanOakley I (think) I know how to use an image as background. I wanted to add button, and now I have trouble with it!

Comment: @martineau this is also my question that why my code is not working and how to fix it.

Comment: dariushmazlumi: OK, but you need to clarify a little more exactly what you're trying to do: How it should look and how it should work.

Comment: thank's @martineau . I want to display an image, and buttons on it.

Comment: @martineau you mean buttons that have image?nice! but how can I add a number on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple way to do what you want which is much less complex that what I was suggesting in my comments. The essential steps are: Create a `tkinter.Canvas`, display the image on it with `Canvas.create_image()`, next create a `Canvas.create_window()` and finally put the `tkinter.Button` in *that*.  Note that each `Canvas` "window" can only hold one widget, so you'll have to repeat the last *two* steps if you want to put more than one button on the image.

It may be simpler to understand by checking out the code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class CanvasButton:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.number = tk.IntVar()
        self.button = tk.Button(canvas, textvariable=self.number,
                                command=self.buttonclicked)
        self.id = canvas.create_window(50, 100, width=25, height=25,
                                       window=self.button)
    def buttonclicked(self):
        self.number.set(self.number.get()+1)  # auto updates Button

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)

imgpath = 'archipelago_big.gif'
img = Image.open(imgpath)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo)

CanvasButton(canvas)  # create a clickable button on the canvas

root.mainloop()
```

Here's what it looks like after clicking on the button a few times:

[image: screenshot of image displayed by script]