# Removing backgrounds of buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to remove the background of my buttons in tkinter. I have a background for the actual window but the buttons are hiding it.

[image: image of application]

Also help with spacing the buttons vertically would be nice.

Code for buttons:

```py
button1 = Button(button_frame,text='1',font=('times new roman',12),relief='ridge',
           bd=0.3,bg='#e1e1e1',width=8,height=3,command=lambda:press(1))
```

Code for background:

```py
bgimg = PhotoImage(file="Untitled-2.png")
my_label = Label(root, image=bgimg)
my_label.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to have buttons on top of the background image then you need to use Canvas like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843706/how-to-have-an-background-image-and-buttons-on-it-in-tkinter).

However, within Tkinter, the Button widget does not support transparency. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080499/transparent-background-in-a-tkinter-window?rq=) you will find some solutions for it but it is OS-dependant.

For positioning the widget you will need *grid layout* :

```
btnRun = Button(root, text='Run', command=myfunction)
btnRun.configure(state="disabled", fg="white")
btnRun.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=20, ipadx=22)
```

You can adjust widgets like this in grid layout as per requirement.

Comment: Bruh. Well thank you. This actually sucks though. Do you know how to add vertical spacing inbetween the buttons? That would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have updated my answer for layout and positioning the widget