# Grid and Pack same time :( what can i do to use pack or grid together or is there another way

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, pack

well i need to set a background image for my program but i knew a few minutes ago that grid and pack can't be used together so ii am asking if there is any other way for me to set a background image and not loosing my buttons and labels
Here is a part of my program need help please:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
root=Tk()
root.title('COVID-19')
ttk.Button(text='About').grid()
myimage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('... .jpg'))
mylabel=Label(image=myimage)
mylabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use an image for the background in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158552/how-to-use-an-image-for-the-background-in-tkinter)