# Open window with image using button in Python

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to open a new window which includes an image. I don't know how to achieve this. Currently, my code opens up a plain window with a button saying show image.

```
from tkinter import * 
from PIL import ImageTk, Image




root = Tk()
root.configure(background = "black")
obrazek = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("dn.jpg"))
def click():
    
    MyLabel = Label(root, image = obrazek)
    Tk()
    MyLabel.pack()


myButton = Button(root, text = "Wyjście", command = click, fg = "white", bg = "#000000")
myButton.pack()


mainloop()
```

Comment: dont use `Tk()` twice, use `Toplevel` instead

Comment: also [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158552/how-to-use-an-image-for-the-background-in-tkinter)

Comment: how to show a picture in a new button pop-up ?

Comment: @Paramonow do you want the button to have an image or the window?

Comment: I want to show the picture after pressing the button, sorry for the inaccuracy

Comment: Say `top = Toplevel()` and make your label to `Label(top,....)` and then make sure to remove `Tk()`.

Comment: I followed your instructions but after pressing the button the program opens an empty window with no image

Comment: `MyLabel` is packed in the *root* window, not the newly open window.

Comment: I put minimal working example in answer. If you need more then you can search on my [blog](https://blog.furas.pl/category/pythontkinter.html) or in examples in my repo [python-examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/). I speak Polish.

Comment: @furas i have a question, is it possible to loop pop-up images, e.g. after clicking a button, 10 images pop up, etc ?

Comment: I dont know if I understand. On blog I have [Tkinter: Update image on Canvas with Button click](https://blog.furas.pl/python-tkinter-update-image-on-canvas-with-button-click-gb.html) (PL: [Tkinter: Zmiana obrazka na Canvas po wciśnięciu Button'a](https://blog.furas.pl/python-tkinter-zmiana-ograzka-na-canvas-po-wcisnieciu-button.html)) and there is `Change many times - and cicle images` which shows how to use list with three images (red,yellow, green) to display different image on every button click.

Comment: if you want to open 10 windows at once when you click 1 button then you can do it. In `click()` you can use loop to create 10 Toplevel windows and display different image from some list.

Comment: where i must place while true:  ?

Comment: what `while True`? To create 10 windows you need `for x in range(10)`. But if you thing to repeate some work all time - ie replace image every 30 seconds - then don't use `while True` but `after(30, other_function)`. Using `while True` you will block `mainloop` and code will freeze.

Answer (score 1):

This is minimal working example.

You have to use `Tk()` only to create main window. For other windows you have to use `Toplevel`. And when you have it in variable ie. `top` then you have to use it as first argument in `Label` (or other widget) to display widget in this window.

**BTW:** [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```
#from tkinter import *  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred 

import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

# --- functions ---

def click():
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    my_label = tk.Label(top, image=my_image)
    my_label.pack()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
#root.configure(background="black")  # PEP8: without spaces around `=`

my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("lenna.png"))  # PEP8: english names

my_button = tk.Button(root, text="Wyjście", command=click)  # PEP8: lower_case_names for variables
my_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Image from Wikipedia: [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna)

---

**EDIT:**

I hope you didn't create `PhotoImage` inside function because there is bug in `PhotoImage` which removes image from memory when it is assigned to local variable in function. And then you can see empty image. It has to be assigned to global variable or to some object - ie. `my_label.img = image`