# Is it possible to move an image in Tkinter to the very back?

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

In the program, I've put an image in, but am unsure how to put the image to the very back, behind the other widgets. Right now, it is above some of the widgets meaning it is covering them .

[The code file is 33000 characters so I have posted a link](https://newtextdocument.com/af1c44a312)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution:

Im not sure if this is the solution to your problem, but I'm not gonna read a 33000 line code :p.

This person uses "place" to fix an image to the backgroud.

```py
bgd_img=tk.PhotoImage(...)
bgd_lbl = tk.Label(parent, image=background_image)
bgd_lbl.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158552/how-to-use-an-image-for-the-background-in-tkinter#:~:text=One%20simple%20method%20is%20to,is%20really%20good%20at%20doing.&text=You%20can%20then%20grid%20or,has%20a%20lower%20stacking%20order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158552/how-to-use-an-image-for-the-background-in-tkinter#:%7E:text=One%20simple%20method%20is%20to,is%20really%20good%20at%20doing.&text=You%20can%20then%20grid%20or,has%20a%20lower%20stacking%20order).