# Adding an image as background in a Tkinter Window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I have a Python script that creates three Tkinter windows. I want to add an image as the background and display all other widgets on top of it. Can anyone suggest how to achieve this in Tkinter?

```
import tkinter as tk, pandas as pd, io
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog

class DataWizard:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Data Wizard: Automated Data Preprocessing")
        self.root.geometry("800x600")

        # Top layout with title
        self.title_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Data Wizard: Automated Data Preprocessing", font=("Arial", 18))
        self.title_label.pack(pady=20)

        # Middle layout with table frame
        self.table_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        self.table_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)

        # Create a treeview widget to display table
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.table_frame, selectmode='browse')
        self.tree.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Add scrollbar to the treeview widget
        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.table_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        # Bottom layout with Upload CSV file label and button
        self.bottom_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        self.bottom_frame.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.upload_label = tk.Label(self.bottom_frame, text="Upload CSV file", font=("Arial", 12))
        self.upload_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.upload_button = tk.Button(self.bottom_frame, text="Browse", command=self.upload_csv)
        self.upload_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10, pady=10)

        
        self.new_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bd=0, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        self.new_frame.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=20, pady=10)
        
        # Add button to open a new window
        self.new_window_button = tk.Button(self.new_frame, text="Next", command=self.open_new_window)
        self.new_window_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10, pady=10)

    def upload_csv(self):
        # Open file dialog to select a CSV file
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("CSV files", "*.csv")])

        if file_path:
            # Read CSV file as pandas dataframe
            self.df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

            # Set the columns of the treeview widget based on the dataframe columns
            self.tree["columns"] = list(self.df.columns)

            # Set column headings and widths based on the dataframe
            for col in self.df.columns:
                self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title())
                self.tree.column(col, width=len(str(self.df[col].max())), anchor = tk.CENTER)

            # Insert data into treeview widget
            for i, row in self.df.iterrows():
                self.tree.insert("", "end", values=list(row))

            # Change the upload label to the filename
            self.upload_label.config(text=file_path)

            # Add horizontal scrollbar to the treeview widget
            horizontal_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.table_frame, orient="horizontal", command=self.tree.xview)
            horizontal_scrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
            self.tree.configure(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set)

    def open_new_window(self):
        new_window = tk.Toplevel()
        new_window.title("New Window")
        
        # Set the window size to full screen
        # Set the window size to full screen
        new_window.state('zoomed')

        # Create a text widget to display the info
        text_widget = tk.Text(new_window, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, width=70, height=20)
        text_widget.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=10, sticky="nw")

        # Redirect the output of df.info() to the text widget
        with io.StringIO() as stream:
            self.df.info(buf=stream)
            output = stream.getvalue()
            text_widget.insert(tk.END, output)
            
        # Make the text widget uneditable
        text_widget.config(state="disabled")
                
        # Create a text widget to display the info
        text_widget2 = tk.Text(new_window, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, width=70, height=22)
        text_widget2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=15, pady=5, sticky="sw")
             
        f = tk.Frame(new_window)
        f.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=15, pady=10, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")

        text_widget3 = tk.Text(f, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, width=80, height=3)
        inputs_frame = tk.Frame(f, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, pady=20, width=text_widget3["width"])
        text_widget4 = tk.Text(f, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, width=80, height=24)
        preprocess_button = tk.Button(f, relief=tk.GROOVE, text="Perform Preprocessing", width=10, command=self.preprocess_data)

        text_widget3.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        inputs_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        text_widget4.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        preprocess_button.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        # Add labels and text inputs to the inputs frame
        label1 = tk.Label(inputs_frame, text="Label 1:")
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
        input1 = tk.Entry(inputs_frame)
        input1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
        
        label2 = tk.Label(inputs_frame, text="Label 2:")
        label2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
        input2 = tk.Entry(inputs_frame)
        input2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
        
        add_button = tk.Button(inputs_frame, text="Add", width=10)        
        add_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)
        
    def preprocess_data(open_new_window):
        preprocessed_window = tk.Toplevel()
        preprocessed_window.title("Preprocessed Data")
        preprocessed_window.geometry("800x600")
               
        #Use tocsv methods to convert preprocessed dataframe of pandas into a csv file and then also seek how to make it downloadable
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = DataWizard(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

The output of the code is:
[image: Main Window]
[image: TopLevel Window named new_window]

I have tried putting the canvas, then the image in it, ad then other widgets in it, but that won't also work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use an image for the background in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158552/how-to-use-an-image-for-the-background-in-tkinter)

Comment: Which window main or toplevel?

Comment: @Marijn I tried the label method as well, but even that won't work!

Comment: @toyotaSupra All the windows, including the one main window and other two TopLevel Windows!

Comment: Try using tk.PhotoImage or PIL ImageTk.PhotoImage then use the place manager for your widgets

Comment: Note that tkinter widgets don't support transparent background, so those frames will cover the background image.