# Unable to load image in canvas class from tkinter module

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

My code displays two sides of a card.

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
import random as r
import time


BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#B1DDC6"
FRONT_SIDE_IMAGE = r"D:\python course\day 31 - flash card capstone project\images\card_front.png"
BACK_SIDE_IMAGE = r"D:\python course\day 31 - flash card capstone project\images\card_back.png"
CORRECT_BUTTON_IMAGE = r"D:\python course\day 31 - flash card capstone project\images\right.png"
INCORRECT_BUTTON_IMAGE = r"D:\python course\day 31 - flash card capstone project\images\wrong.png"
DATA_FILE_PATH = r"D:\python course\day 31 - flash card capstone project\data\french_words.csv"

# front background image
bg_canvas = Canvas(width=800, height=526,
                   bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR, highlightthickness=0)
front_img = PhotoImage(file=FRONT_SIDE_IMAGE)
card_img = bg_canvas.create_image(400, 263, image=front_img)
language = bg_canvas.create_text(
    400, 150, text="French", font=("Arial", 40, "italic"))
card_word = bg_canvas.create_text(
    400, 263, text="", font=("Arial", 60, "bold"))
bg_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to load the "card_img" and it just shows that background colour. Will be grateful for guidance!

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: Any errors that you are getting?

Comment: Is the code inside a function actually?

Comment: @BentheCoder No. I am not getting any errors, it's just that the image is not showing up, rather the `BACKGROUND_COLOR` is set as the background.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use an image for the background in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158552/how-to-use-an-image-for-the-background-in-tkinter)

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer to your question by clicking on the checkmark below the up and down vote buttons!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is to set the background of your `tkinter` window, something like this (image credit of Educba):
[image: Screenshot of result]

If that's what you are trying to do, then you can look at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158552/how-to-use-an-image-for-the-background-in-tkinter), (that's the duplicate I was talking about before).

So use the following code (this was found in Bryan Oakley's answer, I didn't create this):

```py
background_image=tk.PhotoImage(...)
background_label = tk.Label(parent, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

And if you are creating and showing the image in a function, prevent the image from being garbage collected by Python by creating a variable that holds an instance of the image, like this:

```
background_label.image = background_image
```

You should now have a background image in your GUI!

P.S. You can also take a peek at https://www.educba.com/tkinter-background-image.